# 2 unique field combination vice versa

Tags: mysql, database-design

Hello is it possible to have a combination of 2 fields vice versa ?

Example:

```
ID  catID
 1    58
```

So that we couldnt store another row as 58-1. Currently I have primary key on both fields, but it allows me to store 58-1 combination.

thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Create a trigger.

Comment: to store related links without having duplicates. My select statement checks for both fields ID and catID, so that we dont store 2 records for 2 categories, but one. I guess its not possible then.

Comment: no probs, I thought it can be done via structure. Its just a precaution, I will have to check first and not store dups.

Answer (score 0):

You would combine the two fields using `concat()`:

```
select concat(id, '-', catId) as CombinedId
from t;
```

You can encapsulate this in a view, if you like.

You can use `CombinedId` to join to another table, if you like.

However, this isn't recommended.  If you want to compare, than use the two values independently.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ID` and `catID` are symmetrical<sup>1</sup>, you could simply:

```
CHECK (ID < catID)
```

Or possibly (depending on your requirements):

```
CHECK (ID <= catID)
```

---

*<sup>1</sup> I.e. `(ID = X, catID = Y)` is equivalent to `(ID = Y, catID = X)` for every `X` and `Y`.*